# Materialize css using sass

Tags: sass, materialize

I am starting a new project using materializecss. I wanted to use the Sass setup but when I run: `gem 'materialize-sass'` I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command materialize-sass
```

I have ruby installed as I use Sass on a daily basis so I am not exactly sure what the issue is here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the materialize-sass gem installed?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but not quite the same.

It looks like you need the gem installed first.

Run

```
gem install materialize-sass
```

-to install seperately, as per https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass